# How to check if a variable has the same value as any other in a list/array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a list of variables (for example: userList = [user1, user2, user3...]) and each one of them is stored in local storage and has a value of either 1 or 0.
Now I'm trying to make it so if one value from the array (for example user 2) has a value of 1, every other variable in than array has its value set to 0.

This is my array (it's pretty long so I only put in 3 values) :

```
var usernameAlphaLog = [
  localStorage.getItem("user1-log"), 
  localStorage.getItem("user2-log"), 
  localStorage.getItem("user3-log")...
]
```

Comment: So the first "1" found from start will make the rest following it "0" ? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Comment: To be a bit more specific, I made a login/registration and the problem is that I can log in as multiple users at once. For example I can log in as user2 (thus setting the value of user2 to 1) but I can also log in as user3 (for example), now I have two users logged in which shouldn't happen. What I'm trying to do is basically to set all the values to 0 and only leave the value of the user that is currently/should be logged in to 1.

Comment: One solution that should work is to set all values besides the user loggin in to 0 (for example I log in as user3 and it sets the user 3 value to 1 and every other value to 0 by doing user1==0,user2==0,user3==0... and so on) but this isn't really efficient as you manually have to add every user and have it set the value to 0.  
Another solution is to set all (including the current user) values to 0 and then set the current user's value to 1, but I don't know how to do this (I know it can probably be done with a loop but I don't know how to do it) although it's basically what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you're doing it incorrectly.

Use an object instead, with keys, and store it as JSON

```
var users = {user1 : 1, user2 : 0, user3 : 0, user4 : 0 };
```

Then, when you want to change something, you do

```
for (var key in users) users[key] = 0;
users['user2'] = 1;
```

and you've set `user2` to `1`, and all the others to `0`
To store it, you'd do

```
localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users));
```

and to fetch it

```
var users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users'));
```

This is a lot simpler than storing each key/value pair in local storage, and can easily be extended with functions that update, change etc.

Comment: and even `users['user'+x] = 1;`

Comment: Could you explain to me a bit how this works / what it exactly does because I've never worked with nor seen this (I'm new to javascript), I'm only familiar with the standard for loop :
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
}
but anyway, thank you for your answer.

Comment: The first part is just a regular object, with keys and values. The loop is a for..in loop, that should be used with objects, and then it's converted to a string when stored in local storage, and parsed back to an object when fetched from local storage.